# How to remove part of string ahead of special character in a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have this simple dataframe:

```
In [101]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['ciao','hotel',"l'hotel"]})

In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
   a           b
0  1        ciao
1  2       hotel
2  3     l'hotel
```

The goal here is to remove the part of the strings ahead the `'` apostrophe, so that df:

```
   a           b
0  1        ciao
1  2       hotel
2  3       hotel
```

So far I tried to split the string with `sep=("'")` and get the second element only, but it failed since I have strings (and therefore lists) with different length:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: x.split("'")[1])
```

Comment: It should be possible with regular expressions. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-1` to always get the *last* part rather than the *second* part.

```
df['c'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: x.split("'")[-1])

print(df)

#    a        b      c
# 0  1     ciao   ciao
# 1  2    hotel  hotel
# 2  3  l'hotel  hotel
```

However, keep in mind that this will brake if you have have strings with 2 or more apostrophes (but your requirement doesn't specify what to do in these cases anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select last list by `-1`:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].str.split("'").str[-1]
print (df)
   a        b      c
0  1     ciao   ciao
1  2    hotel  hotel
2  3  l'hotel  hotel
```

Or use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['c'] = df['b'].str.replace("(.*)'", '')
print (df)
   a        b      c
0  1     ciao   ciao
1  2    hotel  hotel
2  3  l'hotel  hotel
```